# How do I toggle the elements with its corresponding button by mapping through an array in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<div>
    {arrayOfDetails.map((deets, index) => (
            <div>
                <h1>{deets.firstName + ' ' + deets.lastName}</h1>
                <div>
                    <div id={index}>
                        {listOfGrades(deets.grades)}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autoComplete="off">+</button>
            </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

I'm mapping through an array from a JSON.
How do I get the button to toggle the display of the div containing listOfGrades with the ID?

So 20 buttons for 20 listOfGrades divs, and each button should toggle its own corresponding div.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Any affort?

Comment: PR7 below answered it. I didn't know I can use the index in the onClick in that way. I couldn't find anybody else that wrote it like that.
Thanks for viewing this and helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property in your data which keeps track of the `hidden` state. Then on button click for a row, find the index and toggle `hidden` property for that row.

```
  const [deets, setDeets] = useState([]); // Set initial Value here with hidden property for each item in array

  const toggleElement = (idx) => {
    let newDeets = [...deets];
    deets[idx].hidden = !deets[idx].hidden;
    setDeets(newDeets);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {arrayOfDetails.map((deets, index) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{deets.hidden ? "" : `${deets.firstName} ${deets.lastName}`}</h1>
          <div>
            {deets.hidden ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <div id={index}>{listOfGrades(deets.grades)}</div>
            )}
          </div>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-toggle="button"
            aria-pressed="false"
            autoComplete="off"
            onClick={() => toggleElement(index)}
          >
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! this was the answer! I didn't know i had to put {() => toggleElement(index)} for the onClick!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

add a property `isActive` to each data object.

for example :

```
setArrayOfDetails(dataComingFromServer.map(item=>({...item,isActive:true})))
```

create the callback for toggling active status:

```
const toggleActive=(index)=>{

 const newState=[...arrayOfDetails]
 newState[i].isActive=!newState[i].isActive
 setArrayOfDetails(newState)
}
```

now render the items that are active:

```
<div>
{arrayOfDetails.map((deets, index) => (
        <div>
            <h1>{deets.firstName + ' ' + deets.lastName}</h1>
             <div>
             {deets.isActive &&  <div id={index}>
                    {listOfGrades(deets.grades)}
                </div>}
            </div>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autoComplete="off" onClick={()=>toggleActive(index)}>+</button>
        </div>
))}
```

Comment: This will hide the toggle button as well.